stalenessOf vs invisibilityOf in Selenium Java
Could you explain the differences between stalenessOf vs invisibilityOf?
Both checked if element invisible/no attached to the DOM. And can't understand when should implement one instead of other
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element));

both passes when element is disappeared

stalenessOf is for waiting until previously located element is removed from the DOM.
invisibilityOf is for waiting until an element is invisible.
The is an overlap between the cases, a deleted element is also invisible. However there are differences, for example an element with style="display: none;" will be invisible but not stale.
You can also see the difference in the implementation
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> stalenessOf(final WebElement element) {
  return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver ignored) {
      try {
        // Calling any method forces a staleness check
        element.isEnabled();
        return false;
      } catch (StaleElementReferenceException expected) {
        return true;
      }
    };
  }


public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> invisibilityOf(final WebElement element) {
  return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
      return isInvisible(element);
    }
  };
}


staleness doesn't necessarily mean removed from DOM.  (any update can cause stale)  These are references to the elements in the DOM... any change to the DOM can cause that reference to be stale even if the particular element has not changed at all.  (for instance getting the element while the DOM is in the process of updating... and then trying a method on it... the method will trigger the StaleElementException.. it's really the reference that's stale)

if you look at the "isInvisible" method, they've made a comment there that's incorrect:  try {
return !element.isDisplayed();
} catch (StaleElementReferenceException | NoSuchElementException ignored) {
// We can assume a stale element isn't displayed.
return true;
}  You cannot assume that a stale element isn't displayed... you can only assume that the element reference is stale.  (the element that the reference used to point to may in fact be visible)
